# how to install opencv on Mac and use in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have try to use `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` to install opencv on my mac which write in this [post](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv).

But, When I try to import `cv2` model in python. An error occurred:

`Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  3 2017, 12:34:11)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
\>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/keen/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/keen/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.2.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found`

It looks like that python cat't find `libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib`

What should I do next?

Comment: Have you tried pip install opencv-python?

Comment: Thank you to help me , It works !